# "sheds some important insights"?

Tags: expressions, expression-choice

Could we say "sheds some important insights"?

E.g. The discussion sheds some important insights for optimizing an HTML parser

If this is not appropriate, what is a nice way to express the same idea?

Comment: Presumably the discussion has already taken place - in the past? So it should be *the discussion **shed***.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've never heard anyone use a phrase like that before. The idiom is "[*to shed some light on*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shed+light+on)" not "*to shed some insights for*".

So you could say:

> The discussion *sheds some light on* optimizing an HTML parser.

Or possibly

> The discussion *provides important insights on* optimizing an HTML parser.

I think both of these convey the idea you're trying to express, although the second sentence states it a bit more directly.

Comment: Yes, it appears to be an incoherent melding of _light_ and _(in)sight_, confusing the fixed visual metaphoric phrase _shed light on_ 'make obvious and clear', with the metaphoric use of _insight_ to refer to 'understanding'. Mixing metaphors is like mixing paint; sometimes the result is just muddy.

Comment: This one seems clear enough to me;  “sheds some important insights” means “discards some important insights”.